# GitKraken is not showing repo I am a contributer to

Tags: git, github, repository, gitkraken

I am using GitKraken to manage my repositories from github, and I am able to see and clone repositories I am the owner of no problem.  However, I set up a repository with my school's github account, added many students, and am able to manage it no problem on github.com

However, GitKraken is neither able to see it in my clone from github section, nor is it able to add it by URL.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Adam

---

Error message:

Remote not found.  Double-check your remote url, then make sure you have access to do that action on that remote and try again.

Comment: You mean `collaborators`, right?

Comment: Yes sorry, I mean I am a collaborator

Answer (score 49):

I had this problem too. If your school has its own Github organization, then you will need to go to github.com and in the top right go to `Settings > Authorized applications > GitKraken`.

From here you can grant the GitKraken application access to your school's organization and any other orgs you are a part of:

Here is a shortcut link to the page:
https://github.com/settings/connections/applications/a7557949433b7d282a76

Comment: Thank you, that shortcut is needed if you want to give access to an organisation (as organisations cannot be logged into directly, they are not their own accounts).

Comment: wow, this seems over engineered. Repos can already have fine grained access restrictions, and GitKraken auths via Oauth _and_ SSH keys, yet it needs one more step to authorise it for an organisation. SMH. Thanks for this, never would have found this on my own.

Comment: Documentation about this issue in GitKraken: https://support.gitkraken.com/integrations/github/
Section 'Why can't I see my remotes or repositories in the drop down menu?'

Answer (score 5):

Phreaknik answer is not up-to-date anymore.

2022 answer [from Gitkraken doc](https://help.gitkraken.com/gitkraken-client/github-gitkraken-client/):

1. On Github, click on your top-right avatar then choose "Settings"
2. Search "Applications" under "Integration" group
3. Click on the "Authorized oAuth Apps" tab
4. Click on "Gitkraken" app
5. You should see "Organizations" list and a "Grant" button next to your organization: click on it!

Comment: This process takes me exactly where Phreaknik's link took, only it's longer.

Comment: Strange, I double check and don't have any "Authorized applications" under settings... that's why I added this answer.

Comment: Weird, the link takes me directly to the GitKraken app's page in the settings.

Comment: yes correct, but the "Authorized Application" menu from the original answer is not there, right? 
btw I think the direct link will not work if the id at the end change

Comment: Yes, there is. It's the exact same page for me.