# SSH key issue with organisation repos on Github

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'v recently create a new ssh key like this :
https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

I successfully tested the key like this : 
https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/testing-your-ssh-connection

and even tries to troubleshoot ssh key problems: 
https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey

I can clone my own private repositories in ssh. 
But i CAN'T clone or interact in ssh with my organisation repositorie.

The fact is that i CAN clone/push/interact with my organisation repos in HTTPS.

I am a member of a team in this organisation and i have all the right on the repositories in https.

My question is : how is it possible that my ssh key works with my private repos in ssh but not with my organisations repos and how to fix it ?

Comment: Have you added your SSH key to your github account?

Comment: Yes, when i tipe $ ssh -T git@github.com  in my terminal its say "Hi nicolasdet! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.", when i go to my key settings i see my public key and i can clone private repos in ssh, but not my organisation repos..

Comment: Are you part of an Org that requires SAML? If so, you need to authorize the key https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/authorizing-an-ssh-key-for-use-with-saml-single-sign-on

Comment: I do not think so, i don't have the select button to enable sso next to my ssh key. but I will still ask my organisation admin.

Comment: @NicolasDeTiesenhausen Are you maybe using a GitHub application? If so, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641849/gitkraken-is-not-showing-repo-i-am-a-contributer-to).